# OneToMany using a Map: Order has items, each item has quantity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hashmap, one-to-many

I have to design DB such that I would have a table called Item (to be sold). When an item is created one of its part is quantity. So I plan to have a table item_qty that has item_id and quantity (original quantity that the shopkeeper has).

Now customers would see this item online and place an Order. The desired design is such that an Order can have many items and each item will have a quantity associated (this is the quantity coming from customer e.g. I want to buy 2 pens).

I ideally want to have Order class having:
`Map<Item, Integer> items;`
where Integer field is for the quantity.
and a corresponding table Order_items that has (order_id, item_id, requested_qty).

Is this the right way? If not - what's the best way to do this. Obviously with the current code that I have:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public Map<Item, Integer> getItem() {
    return item;
}
```

I am getting:

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.test.shop.jpa.entity.Order.item[java.lang.Integer]

Many tutorials including Hibernate's suggest a different use case like Customer having a map of Orders mapped as orderId:Order etc. which is obviously not my case.

Please suggest best approach and I will try my best to implement.

Thanks in advance,
Mustafa

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. The structure that is mapped must be an Entity as well. It would be possible do define an entity that holds only the integer in order to provide the value.

But maybe you have a look at @ElementCollection. Btw. why don't you simply add this value to Item?

Comment: Item is an entity in itself so I want to keep quantity different. I did this by Having a new entity OrderedItem that has reference to Item, Order and has a quantity field too. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="item_qty",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="parententity_id"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="item_id")
@Column(name="qty")
private Map<Item, Integer> item;
```